# React Native FlatList not working with constructed data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Works:

```
<FlatList
  data={['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Button title={item} />
  )}
/>
```

Doesn't work (nothing rendered):

```
<FlatList
  data={[...Array(5).keys()].map(String)}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Button title={item} />
  )}
/>
```

What could possibly be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually working, check out the demo below

https://snack.expo.io/H1elODwPb

And the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet,FlatList,Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[...Array(5).keys()].map(String)}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Button title={item} />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Comment: I see nothing on the screen. Try test with Android Nougat?

Comment: No, just checked online using snack.expo.io

Comment: What do u mean? You still have to use an actual device to scan the QR code on snack.expo.io? I just tested with https://snack.expo.io/SJT6PCPPZ, that works, but not yours (nothing on screen).

Comment: Ok i just tested it on the embedded device on expo.io. Your code works for iOS but not Android.